# JSHint doesn't work in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, jshint

On invoking `:SyntasticInfo`:

> Syntastic version: 3.8.0-94 (Vim 800, Linux, GUI)
>   Info for filetype: javascript
>   Global mode: active
>   Filetype javascript is active
>   The current file will be checked automatically
>   Available checker: jshint
>   Currently enabled checker: jshint

I've installed both JSHint and Syntastic via vim-pathogen.

What is one supposed to configure in order to make the syntax checking work?

In [Syntastic's documentation on JSHint](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic-checkers.txt), nothing special is mentioned about configuration, other than

> This checker is initialised using the "makeprgBuild()" function and
>   thus it accepts the standard options described at
>   |syntastic-config-makeprg|.

On a side note, syntax checking *does* work for TypeScript, using Syntastic.

.vimrc:

```
syntax on
colorscheme industry

execute pathogen#infect()
filetype plugin on

set textwidth=0
set softtabstop=4
let &shiftwidth=&softtabstop
set autoindent
set number

" Used for using buffers and tabs the right way.
set hidden

" Enable airline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

" Use powerline fonts
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

"Open NERDTree on startup
"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

:let mapleader = "/"

" Mappings to access buffers (don't use "\p" because a
" delay before pressing "p" would accidentally paste).
" \l       : list buffers
" \b \f \g : go back/forward/last-used
" \1 \2 \3 : go to buffer 1/2/3 etc
nnoremap <Leader>l :ls<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b :bp<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>f :bn<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>g :e#<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>1 :1b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>2 :2b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>3 :3b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>4 :4b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>5 :5b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>6 :6b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>7 :7b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>8 :8b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>9 :9b<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>0 :10b<CR>
" It's useful to show the buffer number in the status line.
"set laststatus=2 statusline=%02n:%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P

" Enable color highlighting by Powerline in vim.
set t_Co=256

" Display buffer number in Airline
 let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_nr_show = 1

" Enable tab support in Airline
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ts setlocal filetype=typescript

" Close a buffer without closing its window
map <Leader>q :bp<bar>sp<bar>bn<bar>bd<CR>

" Split a window without resizing the others
set noequalalways

" Don't autoindent when editing text files --- no suffix filenames.
set noautoindent
augroup vimrc_indent
    au!
    autocmd FileType * set autoindent
augroup END

"Toggle scrolling by display lines instead of file lines.
noremap <silent> <Leader>w :call ToggleWrap()<CR>
function ToggleWrap()
  if &wrap
    echo "Wrap OFF"
    setlocal nowrap
    set virtualedit=all
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Up>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Down>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <Home>
    silent! nunmap <buffer> <End>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Up>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Down>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <Home>
    silent! iunmap <buffer> <End>
  else
    echo "Wrap ON"
    setlocal wrap linebreak nolist
    set virtualedit=
    setlocal display+=lastline
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Up>   gk
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Down> gj
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <Home> g<Home>
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> <End>  g<End>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Up>   <C-o>gk
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <Home> <C-o>g<Home>
    inoremap <buffer> <silent> <End>  <C-o>g<End>
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> k gk
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> j gj
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> 0 g0
    noremap  <buffer> <silent> $ g$
  endif
endfunction

"Disable folding
set foldenable

"JS syntax checking
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['jshint']
```

Comment: Show us your `.vimrc`, particularly as is relates to your Syntastic settings.

Comment: So, what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead?  How did you conclude it doesn't work?

Comment: @lcd047 For instance, for the purpose of checking its functionality, I omitted a closing bracket in a function definition. This doesn't trigger an error by Syntastic. The same for other forms of incorrect syntax.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I've added my .vimrc. :)

Comment: Does the same file trigger an error when you run `jshint` against it with the same options as syntastic?  Syntastic itself doesn't care about JavaScript syntax, you know.

Comment: @lcd047 Yes, running ` :JSHintCheck` or something close does trigger an error by Syntastic, indeed. But I want live checking, not only when I invoke the previous command manually.

Comment: Then you should look for another plugin. Syntastic doesn't do live checks. It also only looks at the files on disk, not at Vim buffers.

Comment: [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) is good for that @lcd047

Comment: @dmfay Neomake does asynchronous checks. It still doesn't do checks on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any configuration for Syntastic telling it to run.  You might start with the recommended settings as listed when you run `:help syntastic-recommended`:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

You can also manually invoke Syntastic with `:SyntasticCheck`

If it is on-the-fly linting that you desire, as recommended in one of the comments, then you should switch from Syntastic to [ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) (I recommend ALE in general)

Comment: ALE works like a charm. :) Too bad Syntastic doesn't support live syntax checking.

Comment: Syntastic was designed before vim integrated job control to allow asynchronous operations.  It was great for what was available at the time.  ALE had the luxury of having the job control available from the start and was specifically designed around this feature.